# MVC 5 - Return radiobutton selection based on model data (on edit page)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with binding my radiobutton model data to my radiobuttons. 
When I insert a record the selected checkbox gets ineerted. However when I edit that same inserted record, the radiobutton which equals the model data one is not selected.

I have 3 different radio buttons which get inserted as char(1) values in my database.

My radiobutton view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">



        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Pigeon.pigeonid)


        @{

            var _Small = Model.Pigeon.size + "_Small";
            var _Medium = Model.Pigeon.size + "_Medium";
            var _Big = Model.Pigeon.size + "_Big";

        }


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Pigeon.size, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Pigeon.size, "s", new { @id = _Small, name = "size" }) Small
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Pigeon.size, "m", new { @id = _Medium, name = "size" }) Medium
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Pigeon.size, "b", new { @id = _Big, name = "size" }) Big
                    </label>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
}
```

The data that is inserted is 's', 'm' or 'b'.
This works fine for the create page but the edit page just doesnt retunr thew selection.

I have already tried multiple things like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">



        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Pigeon.pigeonid)


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Pigeon.size, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Pigeon.size, "s", Model.Pigeon.size == "s" ? new { @checked = "checked" } : null) Small
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Pigeon.size, "m", Model.Pigeon.size == "m" ? new { @checked = "checked" } : null) Medium
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Pigeon.size, "b", Model.Pigeon.size == "b" ? new { @checked = "checked" } : null) Big
                    </label>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

But this also doesn't work. Checked seems to not work because the selection is being determined by the 'Active' class on the label. Any clue how to get this to work?

Comment: show us your `Insert` and `Edit` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're saving the selection as `char` and not as a `string` in the database, can you try changing the `object value`s parameters to `char`s instead of `string`s? (With a single `'` and not double `"`)

For example:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Pigeon.size, 's', new { @id = _Small }) Small
```

EDIT:
Also, remove the name html attribute as the correct one should be something like Pigeon_size (and it will be assigned automatically)

Comment: Good point! Changed it but has no effect on showing the correct 'selected value'.

Comment: @Nicolas you sure that your Model is passed correctly to the View?

Comment: Also, remove the `name` html attribute as the correct one should be something like `Pigeon_size` (and it will be assigned automatically)

Comment: This is the model being passed :     `public class PigeonsViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<GPS.Dal.Models.tblPigeons> Pigeons { get; set; }
        public tblPigeons Pigeon { get; set; }
    }` The non-IEnumerable is being used, the IEnumerableis used for a partial view.